# Get content of Ktor http request

Tags: kotlin, request, ktor

How can i make Ktor feature to get content from ApplicationCall context before routing feature?
Main goal is to get, but not consume, so that all next interceptors can use it.

If we are going something like this in :

```
pipeline.intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
                feature.intercept(this)
                val content = call.receiveText()
                proceed()
            }
```

or like this

```
pipeline.intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
            val params = this.call.receiveParameters().entries()
            proceed()
        }
```

We will have this next step:

```
java.io.IOException: Broken delimiter occurred
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.DelimitedKt$skipDelimiterSuspend$2.doResume(Delimited.kt:57)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.DelimitedKt$skipDelimiterSuspend$2.invoke(Delimited.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.DelimitedKt$skipDelimiterSuspend$2.invoke(Delimited.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.ByteBufferChannel.lookAheadSuspend(ByteBufferChannel.kt:1746)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.DelimitedKt.skipDelimiterSuspend(Delimited.kt:55)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.io.DelimitedKt.skipDelimiter(Delimited.kt:50)
at io.ktor.http.cio.MultipartKt.boundary(Multipart.kt:89)
at io.ktor.http.cio.MultipartKt$parseMultipart$1.doResume(Multipart.kt:158)
at kotlin.coroutines.experimental.jvm.internal.CoroutineImpl.resume(CoroutineImpl.kt:42)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.DispatchedKt.resumeCancellable(Dispatched.kt:209)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:35)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:111)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:165)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.ProduceKt.produce(Produce.kt:95)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.ProduceKt.produce$default(Produce.kt:88)
at io.ktor.http.cio.MultipartKt.parseMultipart(Multipart.kt:145)
at io.ktor.http.cio.MultipartKt.parseMultipart(Multipart.kt:138)
at io.ktor.http.cio.CIOMultipartDataBase.<init>(CIOMultipartData.kt:33)
at io.ktor.http.cio.CIOMultipartDataBase.<init>(CIOMultipartData.kt:31)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultTransformKt.multiPartData(DefaultTransform.kt:70)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultTransformKt.access$multiPartData(DefaultTransform.kt:1)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultTransformKt$installDefaultTransformations$2.doResume(DefaultTransform.kt:44)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultTransformKt$installDefaultTransformations$2.invoke(DefaultTransform.kt)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultTransformKt$installDefaultTransformations$2.invoke(DefaultTransform.kt)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:22)
at io.ktor.request.ApplicationReceiveFunctionsKt.receive(ApplicationReceiveFunctions.kt:64)
at accreditation.controller.RequisitesRoutingKt$requisites$1$1.doResume(RequisitesRouting.kt:54)
at accreditation.controller.RequisitesRoutingKt$requisites$1$1.invoke(RequisitesRouting.kt)
at accreditation.controller.RequisitesRoutingKt$requisites$1$1.invoke(RequisitesRouting.kt)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:22)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:100)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:25)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.doResume(Routing.kt:66)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt:51)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at accreditation.utils.logging.RequestLogger$Feature$install$1.doResume(RequestLogger.kt:80)
at accreditation.utils.logging.RequestLogger$Feature$install$1.invoke(RequestLogger.kt)
at accreditation.utils.logging.RequestLogger$Feature$install$1.invoke(RequestLogger.kt:66)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.doResume(ContentNegotiation.kt:60)
at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt)
at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt:50)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages.intercept(StatusPages.kt:55)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$1.doResume(StatusPages.kt:84)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$1.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$1.invoke(StatusPages.kt:78)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1.doResume(CallLogging.kt:69)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1.invoke(CallLogging.kt)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1.invoke(CallLogging.kt:61)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:22)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.doResume(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt:66)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invoke(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invoke(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt)
at io.ktor.pipeline.PipelineContext.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:49)
at io.ktor.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:22)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.doResume(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:31)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invoke(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invoke(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:10)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:44)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:113)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:165)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:72)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:64)
at kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.handleRequest(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:22)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.channelRead(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:16)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Main idea is to log request content (if it is Json or UrlEncoded) before it is processed in routing feature and to log every response content too.

Comment: What version of ktor are you using, and when is the exception being thrown?

Comment: ktor_version = '0.9.3'

exception is being thrown when routing pipeline (for example) trying to receive request payload (but it is already empty)

Answer (score 0):

IIRC in old versions Ktor would throw if the request body was read twice. 
Currently (0.9.5), it will allow you to read twice, however the second time the body will be empty (consumed).

See docs here: https://ktor.io/servers/calls/requests.html#receiving

Answer (score 0):

This might also happen when the request doesnot contains any parameters